# When searching for a row, counts come back as 0

Tags: c#, datatable

I am currently doing the following to try and get back a particular row in a data table based on the date time.  The issue I am running into is when I run the code I continuously get 0 back for my number of rows and I am not sure as to why.  Here is some code to that maybe someone can pick apart.

```
var myDay = new AnalysisDay(uniqueDate.Date, null, null, null, null);

var daysList = new List<AnalysisDay>();
foreach(var uniqueDate in uniqueDateList)
{
   var myDay = new AnalysisDay(uniqueDate.Date, null, null, null, null);

   var curDate = uniqueDate;

   //This is the area where the rows come back 0 everytime "Start Date Time"
   //occasionally has DBNull values
   var curDatesRows = analysisInfo.Tables[0].Select("StartDateTime = #{0}#", curDate.ToShortDateString()));
}
```

This is the custom class that is referenced throughout,

```
public class AnalysisDay
{
 public  DateTime? Date { get; set; }
 public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public  int? CarNumber { get; set; }
 public  int? RunId { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<AnalysisDay> Items { get; set; }

 public AnalysisDay(DateTime? date, DateTime? time, string strName, int? number, int? runId)
 {
   Date = date;
   Time = time;
   Name = strName;
   CarNumber = carNum;
   RunId = runId;
   Items = new ObservableCollection<AnalysisDay>();
 }
}
```

If I have left anything out or need to provide more information please let me know and I will update this as soon as possible.

Comment: what does uniqueDateList contain?

Comment: We can do nothing with the excerpt you've posted of your code. You should give more details of your code in order to be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about the comparison must be failing. I usually use LINQ to query instead:

```
var curDatesRows
    = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime?>("StartDateTime").HasValue
                    && x.Field<DateTime>("StartDateTime").Date == curDate.Date);
```

I tested this out on some sample data - it will filter out rows with a null value.

Note that if `curDate` has a time portion, and it doesn't match exactly what's in the table, then you won't get any rows unless you use `.Date` to drop the time portion when doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a short date string as the filter against a column containing date time values (which include time components). I believe that either no date in the `startDateTime` column will match the filter, or only values where the time component is all zeros (which is unlikely, unless you are modifying the times before persisting.

Without additional information, it's hard to tell. Can you show us some sample data from the table? Specifically, the `startDateTime` column?